Using Redis sentinel in a kubernetes environment where snapshot and AOF is off, still seeing the rdb file within the container?
I have a simple deployment in my local using minikube, where I deployed a redis sentinel using helm. That's the configmap configuration related to RDB and AOF.
    # User-supplied common configuration:
    # Enable AOF https://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file
    #appendonly yes
    # Disable RDB persistence, AOF persistence already enabled.
    #save 5 1
    save ""
    # End of common configuration


As you can see RDB is disabled as well as AOF.
Here are the sentinel instances of Redis, 1 master 2 worker.
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
default       redis-node-0                       2/2     Running   0             16m
default       redis-node-1                       2/2     Running   0             15m
default       redis-node-2                       2/2     Running   0             14m


When I exec into redis-node-0 I see nothing inside /data directory, as I expected.
However, for redis-node-1 and redis-node-2 there are dump.rdb files within the /data directory.
Why it is the case? I though I disabled snapshot feature totally.
It behaves like that because this is redis sentinel?
